# Search engine application with solr and sunspot

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine, sunspot

I have pdf/word/html documents containing around approx 700-800 pages on an average. I want to build a rails search engine application using solr/lucene and sunspot gem. How can I manage these documents' storage? Shall I parse whole documents and store it in database or search directly in documents. Which one is scalable and performance oriented option? Consider I have documents around 1-2 lacs.

Comment: I think this link is also similar to above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739193/searching-attachments-from-a-rails-app-word-pdf-excel-etc 
http://rny.io/rails/elasticsearch/2013/08/05/full-text-search-for-attachments-with-rails-and-elasticsearch.html